# Изменить цветовую тему приложения с помощью Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Нужна помощь. Необходимо менять цветовую тему приложения (через стили класса body) с помощью Vuex. Переход между двумя цветовыми темами завязан на переходе с одного языка на другой. Необходимо менять класс body с переключением языка.

Story state:

```
export default {
  language: {
    current: { name: 'en'},
    available: [{ name: 'en' }, { name: 'ru' }]
  }
}
```

Story action:

```
export default { ['app:language:change']({ commit }, language) { 
 commit('app:language:change', language); },
}
```

Story mutation:

```
export default { ['app:language:change'](state, language) { 
 state.language.current = language; },
}
```

Компонент-переключатель языка:

```
<tempalte v-for="(lang, index) in availableLanguages">
   <span style="cursor: pointer;"  v-on:click="() => 
     onLanguageChange(lang)">{{ lang.name }}</span>
   <span v-if="index !== availableLanguages.length - 1"> / </span>
</tempalte>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'app-footer',
    computed: {
     language()
       {return this.$store.state.language.current;},
     availableLanguages() 
       {return this.$store.state.language.available;}
    },
    methods: {
      onLanguageChange(lang) {
        this.$store.dispatch('app:language:change', lang); }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Пример компонента, куда язык подключается:

```
<template>
    <h1> {{ language && title && title[language.name] }} </h1>
</template>
<script>
    const ABOUT_DIC = {
       title: {
         en: 'About',
         ru: 'Компания'
       }
     };
     export default {
        name: 'about',
        data () {
           return { title: ABOUT_DIC.title }
        },
        computed: {
            language() {
               return this.$store.state.language.current; }
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: так а что не работает? или мы должны сами догадаться?